# Whats up with these unicoins?

Tags: support, fun

Weird and funny is the idea of the unicoins. Who created it? Does this influence totally TeX.SX? What is the purpose of it? Was this a feature request?

Answer (score 8):

[Unicoins is a short-lived April fool's initiative](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/227641/168244) from the Stack Exchange group. Apart from the [outrageous and sometimes hilarious discussions about Unicoins on Meta.SO](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/227363/168244), they won't make you richer, [not here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/227898/168244) nor in the real world.

The Unicoins disclaimer:

> Availability may be limited based on factors. Prohibited where void. Stack Exchange Inc. does not endorse or encourage behaviors that should not be endorsed or encouraged. Not legal tender except in localities with citizenship rights for unicorns. Stack Exchange Inc. reserves the right to amend, cancel, or continue this promotion for any reason, including, but not limited to, any reason that would interfere with the invariance, continuation, or non-existence thereof.

You can find more information on this singular event by [searching the tag `[unicoins]` on Meta.SO](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/unicoins?sort=newest&pageSize=50).